# Quarkus Kafka Deserializing Exception to Dead Letter Queue

Tags: error-handling, apache-kafka, deserialization, quarkus, smallrye

In order to satisfy reliability of my service, I need to push all incoming messages, that could not be deserialized, into a dead-letter topic using `kafka-smallrye` and `quarkus`.

All the messages on the topic should be in avro format (but I could not be sure) with a define schema on a schema-registry.

I have set the configuration of my consumer in this way:

```
mp:
  messaging:
    incoming:
      test-in:
        connector: smallrye-kafka
        group:
          id: test-in-consumer-group
        topic: events-topic
        failure-strategy: dead-letter-queue
        schema:
          registry:
            url: http://localhost:8081
        value:
          deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          subject:
            name:
              strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
        key:
          deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          subject:
            name:
              strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
        specific:
          avro:
            reader: true
```

My consumer code:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Consumer {

    @Incoming("test-in")
    public CompletionStage<Void> store(KafkaRecord<Key,SpecificRecord> data ){
            String schemaFullName = data.getPayload().getSchema().getFullName();
            System.out.println(schemaFullName);

            // other consumer code
            return data.ack();
    }
}
```

When the consumer can't deserialize a message, the consuming process is blocked instead move the message to the dead letter and continue. I suppose that a deserialization error not produce an `nack` so the message could not be moved to the dead-letter.

There is a way to move not deserilizable message to the dead letter topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i resolved using DeserializationFailureHandler.
You have to use the topic of "dead-letter-queue" as normal topic and send your failure pushing.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Identifier("failure-dead-letter") // Set the name of the failure handler
public class MyDeserializationFailureHandler
    implements DeserializationFailureHandler<CustomBean> { // Specify the expected type

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyDeserializationFailureHandler.class);

    @Inject
    @Channel("dead-letter")
    Emitter<DeadLetterBean> deadLetterBeanEmitter;

    @Override
    public CustomBean handleDeserializationFailure(String topic, boolean isKey, String deserializer, byte[] data,
                                           Exception exception, Headers headers) {
        LOGGER.error("ERROR: " + exception.getMessage());
        deadLetterBeanEmitter.send(Message.of(new DeadLetterBean(topic, isKey, deserializer, data, exception))
                                          .withAck(() -> {
                                              // Called when the message is acked
                                              LOGGER.error("SENT TO DEAD LETTER");
                                              return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                                          })

                                          .withNack(throwable -> {
                                              // Called when the message is nacked
                                              LOGGER.error("ERROR, NOT SENT DEAD LETTER");
                                              return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                                          }));
        return null;
    }
}
```

also register the new topic as publisher,and the deserialization-failure-handler

```
    mp.messaging.outgoing.dead-letter.topic=dead-letter-topic-name
    mp.messaging.outgoing.dead-letter.value.serializer=io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.ObjectMapperSerializer
    mp.messaging.incoming.message-in.value-deserialization-failure-handler=failure-dead-letter
```